# Error in creating dataset on matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-mining

I'm trying to create a dataset on matlab 12 using the following code

```
C = dataset('File', 'zoo.txt', 'VarNames',{'animalname','hair','feathers',...
'eggs','milk','airborne','aquatic','predator','toothed', 'backbone',...
'breathes', 'venomous', 'fins',...
'legs', 'tail','domestic','catsize','type'}, 'Delimiter', ',')
```

but it shows me these errors
Error using setvarnames (line 36)
Duplicate variable names.

Error in dataset/readFile (line 235)
a = setvarnames(a,varNames(:)',[],true,true);

Error in dataset (line 339)
                a = readFile(a,fileArg,otherArgs);

can anyone help?
[Here you are the zoo.txt file](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/zoo/zoo.data)

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed,

number columns are too few, add a new column at the end

```
 C = dataset('File', 'zoo.txt', 'VarNames',{'animalname','hair','feathers',...
 'eggs','milk','airborne','aquatic','predator','toothed', 'backbone',...
 'breathes', 'venomous', 'fins',...
 'legs', 'tail','domestic','type','x'}, 'Delimiter', ',')
```

see the x. It works for me.

It returns

> C =
>
> ```
> animalname        hair    feathers    eggs    milk    airborne    aquatic
> 'antelope'        1       0           0       1       0           0      
> 'bass'            0       0           1       0       0           1      
> 'bear'            1       0           0       1       0           0      
> 'boar'            1       0           0       1       0           0      
> 'buffalo'         1       0           0       1       0           0      
> 'calf'            1       0           0       1       0           0      
> 'carp'            0       0           1       0       0           1
> ```
>
> ....

Comment: you mean i must change the 18 variable names?

Comment: see the new answer ;-)

Comment: i added the x but the problem is the same

Comment: my code is C = dataset('File', 'zoo.txt', 'VarNames',{'animalname','hair','feathers',...
'eggs','milk','airborne','aquatic','predator','toothed', 'backbone',...
'breathes', 'venomous', 'fins',...
'legs', 'tail','domestic','type','x'}, 'Delimiter', ',')

Comment: Ahmed just a check: you give me the "zoo.data" but the code try to open "zoo.txt"....check the name file

Comment: i'm saving it on my lap zoo.txt

Comment: i can not understand where is the duplication